# Move cart & compare blocks to top links - Problem with dynamic/lazy block

Tags: blocks, cache, ce-1.9.1.0, varnish, mini-cart

I'm trying to move the cart & compare blocks to top links and when the user goes over the `li` the cart/product compare appears: it works.
**Minicart**

```
<reference name="header">
    <reference name="top.links">
        <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
        <block type="minicart/view" name="minicart_toplink" template="minicart/toplink.phtml" >
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="topcart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
        </block>
        <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>minicart_toplink</blockName></action>
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link_minicart">
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</reference>
```

**Minicompare**

```
<!-- Disable compare product block on left and right sidebar -->
    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild">
            <name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <!-- Add Compare product block to top links -->
    <reference name="header">
        <reference name="top.links">
            <block type="minicompare/view" name="minicompare_toplink" template="minicompare/toplink.phtml" >
                <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" as="topcompare" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>minicompare_toplink</blockName></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
```

The problem is that when I use `Lesti:FPC` or `Varnish` these blocks create problems: with varnish they are duplicated(double link for cart, checkout and product cmopare) and with Lesti (if added under `lazy blocks`) they don't appear when I visit the (any and every) page for the first time, if I relaod they appear, but if I change the page the block reset (no item, total=0, but the items are in the cart) and I have to refresh.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lesti FPC: this solved my problem (I have removed any reference to these blocks from the Dynamic section)

**Lazy Block**

```
catalog.compare.sidebar,
minicart_head
```